# Font rendering Issue - weight in safari in mac os

Tags: css, safari, rendering, font-face

i got a strange font rendering issue on my current project. As you can see in the attached jpgs, the font weight is slightly different on different subpages. This happen only in safari on mac os. >> Same Browser(!) but different font rendering.

The only difference between the two pages is a class, witch got a css pseudo-element (no different font or text properties, just a border.)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAShY.jpg)

Has andybody some advice for me?

Comment: Have you tried another browser? The same problem occurs ?

Comment: you will need to put up some code so that people can replicate the problem.

Comment: Are they different weights or different colors? Does one page have a class/style that darkens the header? Perhaps in adding that pseudo-element class you've overridden some css specificity? A code example would help us troubleshoot.

Comment: The problem occurs only in safari on mac os (not on windows, not on iOS)
it is not a different weight (like regular or bold) or color but a different kind of font rendering whitch results in a slightly different weight
* the css of the pseudoelement (shouldnt) affect the font, it was just a border, display: block and a boxshadow.

Answer (score 1):

This, applied to the body, fixed it in my case:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Thank you anyway!